# Converting "float" in DataSet from SQL to "float" in Web API

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an issues converting dataset ds from SQL server to an object in Web API. The issues is only with the "float" present in the dataset  (ds). I am trying to convert the dataset (ds) into a list of objects. But it throws an error for all the "float". If I exclude all the float, it works fine.

```
private static List<TimesheetDetails> ProcessInfo(DataSet ds)


        {
            bool check = (ds == null);
            List<TimesheetDetails> list = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => new TimesheetDetails
            {
                DetailId = x.Field<int>("DetailId"),
                TimesheetId = x.Field<int>("TimesheetId"),
                Project = x.Field<string>("Project"),
                Ac`enter code here`tivity = x.Field<string>("Activity"),
                Day1 = x.Field<DateTime> ("Day1"),
                **//The Issue comes up here when I try to access the float.**
                Day1Hours = x.Field<float> ("Day1Hours"),
                Day2 = x.Field<DateTime>("Day2"),
                Day2Hours = x.Field<float>("Day2Hours"),
                Day3 = x.Field<DateTime>("Day3"),
                Day3Hours = x.Field<float>("Day3Hours"),
                Day4 = x.Field<DateTime>("Day4"),
                Day4Hours = x.Field<float>("Day4Hours"),
                Day5 = x.Field<DateTime>("Day5"),
                Day5Hours = x.Field<float>("Day5Hours"),
                Day6 = x.Field<DateTime>("Day6"),
                Day6Hours = x.Field<float>("Day6Hours"),
                Day7 = x.Field<DateTime>("Day7"),
                Day7Hours = x.Field<float>("Day7Hours")
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: are they nullable?.. do you need `x.Field<float?>` or `x.Field<Nullable<float>>`

Comment: Yes they are nullable. I tried using the code you gave, throws Error. Thank you though.

Comment: What error is it exactly?

Comment: Well I found a solution for it. The hours are type "float" in sql server. In the above code I tried to convert it to float in c#. But if I convert it to type "double" it works fine.